# Graph Theory triangle (3 colors)

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Show that if the edges of $K_n$ are colored with $n$ different colors, then there must be a triangle where all three edges have distinct colors.

So, I want to use induction on $n$ where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph then the base case would be $n=3$ ($K_3$ graph) because you must have a triangle with three distinct edge colors. Then, I know if I draw it with $n=4$ and so on so forth it is true, but I'm having trouble putting it more eloquently.

Comment: I don't understand. If you properly edge-color $K_n$ with $n$ colors, no intersecting edges can have the same color, so *any* triangle must have distinct colors?

Comment: @gt6989b: The problem is to show that no matter how you edge-color $K_n$, if you use exactly $n$ colors, you must have a triangle whose sides are of three different colors.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Remove one vertex from $K_n$. If the remaining graph is coloured with more than $n-2$ colours you can use induction, otherwise there are at least two colours that are not in remaining graph.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the induction part? I think I understand, but I want to make sure.